# How to reset x and y axis in qcustomplot after replotting (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am trying to crop my data, and replot only a selected part of the graph, but after the replot, the x axis still has the same values, and my graph starts at (0,0) instead of (cropped_starting_value_x, y).
How can I reset the values of the X axis? I've already tryed rescaleaxes, but it's not working.
[Here I only have values from around 19 seconds.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq0YL.png)

```
QCPGraph *mainGraph = Customplott[0]->addGraph();
QCPGraph *SecondaryGraph = Customplott[0]->addGraph();
//QCPGraph *TertiaryGraph = Customplott[Number]->addGraph();

//mainGraph->setAdaptiveSampling(true);
mainGraph->setData(Time_temp, Measured_temp);
mainGraph->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssNone, QPen(Qt::red), QBrush(Qt::white), 3));
mainGraph->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue)); // Magic only happens, when line width == 1

SecondaryGraph->setData(Time_temp, Output_temp);
SecondaryGraph->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));

Customplott[0]->setObjectName("YawRate");
Customplott[0]->xAxis->setLabel("Time [s]");
Customplott[0]->yAxis->setLabel("Yaw Rate");


/* rescale axes according to graph's data */
Customplott[0]->rescaleAxes();
mainGraph->rescaleAxes();
SecondaryGraph->rescaleAxes(true);

Customplott[0]->replot();
```

Every kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method:

```
Customplott[0]->xAxis->setRange(minX, maxX);
```

(documentation [here](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a57d6ee9e9009fe88cb19db476ec70bca))

Comment: Thanks, I tried it before, but I used a "rescale" after, so no wonder it didn't work out for me!